# No tick labels after their rotation

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

The tick labels disappear, when I want to rotate them on the plot.
Here's the code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fg = plt.figure()
fg.canvas.set_window_title('My plot')

ax = fg.add_subplot(1,1,1)   
ax.plot(my_points)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=90)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the figure is drawn, the ticklabels are empty. So calling
`ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels()` before `plt.show()` returns a sequence of empty `Text` objects.

One way to fix this is to call `plt.xticks(rotation=90)` instead of

```
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation='vertical')
```

Another way to fix this is to call `fg.canvas.draw()` before calling `ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels()` to populate the `Text` labels with non-empty strings, but this is inefficient since using `fg.canvas.draw()` and `plt.show()` renders the figure twice, and that's not really necessary since you could just use `plt.xticks`.

---

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fg = plt.figure()
fg.canvas.set_window_title('My plot')
my_points = np.random.randint(10, size=10)
ax = fg.add_subplot(1,1,1)   
ax.plot(my_points)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]